# Why follower_count insight metric returns the number of new followers of a given day, instead of Total number of unique users following?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-insights

It seems there is a bug in the definition of **folower_count** insight metric in Facebook graph API for Instagram Business Accounts.

your_instagram_business_account/insights?metric=follower_count&period=day

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/insights

They wrote that this is "Total number of unique users following the Business Account", but we observed that this metric give us the number of new followers of a given day. Also, there is no information about the number of unfollows, so if on the same day it would be 2 new followers and 2 unfollows, the follower_count will be 0.

Comment: Then file a bug with Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation you provided, `follower_count` is defined as

```
Total number of new followers each day within the specified range
```

so this lines up with expectations. Admittedly I'm answering this a bit late so that definition may have changed since you posted this.

the [`followers_count`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/business_discovery) (note the 's') may be what you're looking for.

Comment: so i assume there is no historical data for the followers, if you own the account? only historical data for "new followers per day", right? you could not even calculate it from the current follower count, because there is no metric to get the "lost followers"...

Comment: The `followers_count` link is now broken. Would be great if you can update this answer with the latest one, so that it is useful once more.

Comment: [It's been suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76213751/5211833) that the doc link should now be https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/business_discovery